# Converting an array of date strings to a date format

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

The source data of the array is from a Sharepoint list. So whenever i pull that data and put it in an array variable it returns a date format like this: Mon Jan 01 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time).

To fix this, i used moment.js to correct the format to 'MM-DD-YYYY'

```
//convert ISO date format to YYYY-MM-DD
for(i=0; i<createdDate_array.length; i++){
    var date = new Date(createdDate_array[i]);
    var newDate = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    convertedDate_array.push(newDate);
}
```

Another problem arises though since it returns an array of string like this:

```
["04-19-2018", "04-19-2018", "04-20-2018"]
```

It's a problem because i am using a Date Picker to filter dates in my site. I tried to use console log and the Date Picker values don't have the enclosing "" while the date values in my array have the enclosing "". Which i think is the source of the problem since it's like text vs date format.

How can i convert my array into a date format just like in the Date Picker?

Comment: Does the date picker require `Date` instantiations?

Comment: Sorry, im pretty new in Javascript. What do you mean with Date instantiations?

Comment: eg `new Date` calls the `Date` constructor

Comment: No, for my date picker this is the only code i used:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzYrYb

Comment: It is already the string, `console.log(typeof(start_date))` return you `string`. I can't see any problem.

Comment: Here's the console log of my date array, start date (date picker) and end date (date picker) respectively: https://imgur.com/a/wY6rttP

I also forgot that i set default value for my date pickers on load: 

document.getElementById("start_date").defaultValue = "2018-01-01";

document.getElementById("end_date").defaultValue = "2018-12-31";

Comment: Can you check what is the format for the datepicker? As per the docs it does accept string and Date instance so that should work. Your defaults are passed in YYYY-MM-DD format but your dates are MM-DD-YYYY see if that is messing things up